# Unknown property 'compaction_strategy_class' with cql 3 and cassandra 2.0.1

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

Using this configuration of cassandra:

```
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9161.
[cqlsh 4.0.1 | Cassandra 2.0.1 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.37.0]
```

When I tried to do:

```
ALTER TABLE snpSearch WITH compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'
```

I obtain this error:

```
Bad Request: Unknown property 'compaction_strategy_class'
```

I know that SizeTieredCompactionStrategy is the default strategy, but i want also to modify the sstables size and this:

```
ALTER TABLE snpSearch WITH compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' AND  compaction_strategy_options:sstable_size_in_mb:10;
```

give me this error:

```
Bad Request: line 1:116 mismatched input ':' expecting '='
```

I read the cql documentation and should be correct, does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct format is:

```
ALTER TABLE snpSearch WITH compaction={'class':'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'};
```

The format for `WITH` options of the `ALTER` command is described [here](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#alterTableStmt). The important part is:

> [...] The supported  (and syntax) are the same as for the CREATE TABLE statement [...]

And the [example from the CQL3.1 documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html) shows how the compaction and compression strategies can be set.

( Tested on `[cqlsh 4.0.1 | Cassandra 2.0.1 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.37.0]`.)